# Excel Locked Cell Query

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I want to allow the user to increase and decrease the decimal places of a locked cell in excel 2007 without allowing other formatting options. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a control such as a spinner or two buttons to the worksheet.  One will add zeros, the other will remove zeros.  Have a cell that stores the number of zeros. When they click the button either subtract or add to the cell value, have a low and high number of zeros.  Then use the format combined with the string function to set the number of zeros in the locked cell.